# Facing issue in minikube

Tags: linux

I am unable to start minikube in my centos7 vm machine.Sharing the minikube status and logs.

status-
 minikube status-

host: Running

kubelet: Running

apiserver: Stopped

kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at

Waiting for pods: apiserver!   Error restarting cluster: wait: waiting for component=kube-apiserver: timed out waiting for the condition

- Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
- https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new